# Python 3 UnicodeEncodeError for characters and smileys in Tweets

Tags: python, python-3.4, tweepy, python-unicode

I'm making a Twitter API, I get tweets about a specific word (right now it's 'flafel'). Everything is fine except this tweet

> b'And when I\'m thinking about getting the chili sauce on my flafel
>   and the waitress, a Pinay, tells me not to get it cos "hindi yan
>   masarap."\xf0\x9f\x98\x82'

I use `print ("Tweet info: {}".format(str(tweet.text).encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')))` to see tweets, but this one gives me UnicodeEncodeError every time and if I erase `decode()` from that line like `print ("Tweet info: {}".format(str(tweet.text).encode('utf-8'))` I can see the actual tweet like above, but I want to convert that `\xf0\x9f\x98\x82` part to a str. I tried everyting, every version of decodes-encodes etc. How can I solve this problem?

**Edit**: Well I just went to that user's Twitter account to see what is that non-ASCII part, and it turns out it's a smile:

[image]

Is it possible to convert that smiley?

**Edit2**: The codes are;

```
...
...
api = tweepy.API(auth)
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q = "flafel",
                           result_type = "recent",
                           include_entities = True,
                           lang = "en").items():

    print ("Tweet info: {}".format(str(tweet.text).encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: Have you tried `print ("Tweet info: {}".format(tweet.text.decode('utf-8')))`? Considering `tweet.text` is returning the bytes object you've posted in the question.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary All tweets are returns in str type. I tried your suggestion and: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary The problem is, there are more tweets has non-ascii characters but decode() convert them nicely, except this tweet. ❤❤ ☀  for example some tweets has these characters, but they are converted.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I edited my question

Comment: Can you post the actual content of `tweet.text` in the question body, because what you've posted in the question is a bytes object.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Edited

Comment: `b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x82'` is the UTF-8 representation of ['FACE WITH TEARS OF JOY' (U+1F602)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f602/index.htm) . See [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f602/fontsupport.htm) for fonts that support it.

Comment: @PM2Ring Well is that possible to convert it? At least convert smiles like to ':D' or ';D' or ':('

Comment: Let's try to fix your error first. I don't understand why you do `str(tweet.text).encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')`. Can you post the output of `print(tweet.text.encode('unicode-escape'))` for that tweet?

Comment: @PM2Ring Well that part turned to `"\\U0001f602'` which is face with tears of joy of Python version, I saw it from your comment.

Comment: Ok. But that doesn't explain why you're doing that weird `str(tweet.text).encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')` thing. Isn't `tweet.text` already a Unicode string? You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: You can get the name of Unicode codepoints using the standard [unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#module-unicodedata)module. And it looks like you can convert emojis in various ways using [Emojipy](https://kaviraj.me/generating-pdf-containing-emoji-python), but I've never used it myself.

Comment: Could you be using Windows? And could you show the full error message?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes I'm working on Windows 7

Comment: @SergeBallesta Here: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 154-154: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk`

Comment: Just search the error message and you will find that your question is neither new nor better phrased than other questions before.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yeah I did lots of times, my question is new.

Comment: Well, if you strip off all the irrelevant stuff, like where you got the string from, you will find that the remainder isn't new. That would also get you closer to creating a minimal but complete example, without which your question is off topic.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Still, that's your opinion. If you think so flag it instead of commenting.

Comment: Oh, I did, and wanted to explain why I flagged it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could arise at the moment you try to use the unicode character `\U0001f602` on Windows. Python-3 is fine for converting it from utf-8 to full unicode an back again, but windows is not able to display it.

I tried this piece of code in different ways on a Windows 7 box:

```
>>> b = b'And when I\'m thinking about getting the chili sauce on my flafel and the waitress, a Pinay, tells me not to get it cos "hindi yan masarap."\xf0\x9f\x98\x82'
>>> u = b.decode('utf8')
>>> u
'And when I\'m thinking about getting the chili sauce on my flafel and the waitress, a Pinay, tells me not to get it cos "hindi yan masarap."\U0001f602'
>>> print(u)
```

Are here is what happened:

- in IDLE (Python GUI interpretor based on Tk), I got this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 139-139: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk

- in a console using a non unicode codepage I got this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f602' in position 139: character maps to <undefined>

(for the attentive reader BMP means here *Basic Multilingual Plane*)

- in a console using utf-8 codepage (chcp 65001) I got no error but a weird display:

  ```
  >>> u
  'And when I\'m thinking about getting the chili sauce on my flafel and the waitr
  ess, a Pinay, tells me not to get it cos "hindi yan masarap."ðŸ˜‚'
  >>> print(u)
  And when I'm thinking about getting the chili sauce on my flafel and the waitres
  s, a Pinay, tells me not to get it cos "hindi yan masarap."ðŸ˜‚
  >>>
  ```

My conclusion is that the error in not in the conversion utf-8 <-> unicode. But it looks that Window Tk version does not support this character, nor any console code page (except for 65001 that simply tries to display the individual utf8 bytes!)

TL/DR: The problem is not in core Python processing nor in the UTF-8 converter, but only at the system conversion that is used to display the character `'\U0001f602'`

But hopefully, as core Python has no problem in it, you can easily change the offending `'\U0001f602'` with a `':D'` for example with a mere `string.replace` (after the code shows above):

```
>>> print (u.replace(U'\U0001f602', ':D'))
```

```
And when I'm thinking about getting the chili sauce on my flafel and the waitress, a Pinay, tells me not to get it cos "hindi yan masarap.":D
```

---

If you want a special processing for all characters outside the BMP, it is enough to know that the highest code for it is `0xFFFF`. So you could use code like that:

```
def convert(t):
    with io.StringIO() as fd:
        for c in t:  # replace all chars outside BMP with a !
            dummy = fd.write(c if ord(c) < 0x10000 else '!')
        return fd.getvalue()
```

Comment: I see, well is there a way to convert parts like `\xf0\x9f\x98\x82` to ':D' at least? It'll be much better than bytes.

Comment: I know that I mean is there a way to find that not-convertable part and convert it to for example ':D', since I can't define all bytes and meanings of them... There must be a way to find auto

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can get the names of Unicode codepoints using the standard [unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#module-unicodedata) module. Here's a small demo:

```
import unicodedata as ud

test = ('And when I\'m thinking about getting the chili sauce on my flafel and the '
    'waitress, a Pinay, tells me not to get it cos "hindi yan masarap."\U0001F602')

def convert_special(c):
    if c > '\uffff':
        c = ':{}:'.format(ud.name(c).lower().replace(' ', '_')) 
    return c

def convert_string(s):
    return ''.join([convert_special(c) for c in s])

for s in (test, 'Some special symbols \U0001F30C, ©, ®, ™, \U0001F40D, \u2323'): 
    print('{}\n{}\n'.format(s.encode('unicode-escape'), convert_string(s)))
```

**output**

```
b'And when I\'m thinking about getting the chili sauce on my flafel and the waitress, a Pinay, tells me not to get it cos "hindi yan masarap."\\U0001f602'
And when I'm thinking about getting the chili sauce on my flafel and the waitress, a Pinay, tells me not to get it cos "hindi yan masarap.":face_with_tears_of_joy:

b'Some special symbols \\U0001f30c, \\xa9, \\xae, \\u2122, \\U0001f40d, \\u2323'
Some special symbols :milky_way:, ©, ®, ™, :snake:, ⌣
```

Another option is to test if a character is in the Unicode ["Symbol_Other"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/So/list.htm) category. We can do that by replacing the

```
if c > '\uffff':
```

test in `convert_special` with

```
if ud.category(c) == 'So':
```

When we do that, we get this output:

```
b'And when I\'m thinking about getting the chili sauce on my flafel and the waitress, a Pinay, tells me not to get it cos "hindi yan masarap."\\U0001f602'
And when I'm thinking about getting the chili sauce on my flafel and the waitress, a Pinay, tells me not to get it cos "hindi yan masarap.":face_with_tears_of_joy:

b'Some special symbols \\U0001f30c, \\xa9, \\xae, \\u2122, \\U0001f40d, \\u2323'
Some special symbols :milky_way:, :copyright_sign:, :registered_sign:, :trade_mark_sign:, :snake:, :smile:
```